# Create second instance of mysqld on windows xp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install the new version of the mysql on the windows7 and windows xp . In few of the computers already a new version of mysql are installed. Here I just want to create a second instance of the service of mysqld with my my_XX.ini file.

I have successfully configured the instance on the windows 7 pc . But can not create instance on the windows xp for the same .

I am trying this code on the command prompt which run as administrator. but it does not start the service

```
sc create mysqld2 binPath= c:\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\mysql\my_XX.ini
```

Even I have tried with the mysqld command to start the mysql as per other my_xx.ini with

```
mysqld --defaults-file=c:\mysql\my_XX.ini
```

I am not able to create a second instance on the windows xp . Please help me to start the second instance of mysql on windows xp with windows service

Comment: try using mysqld --console --defaults-file... to see what error is coming and why service cant be started

Comment: Its saying `plugin 'FADERATED' is disabled` . But it would be better to create service like sc create so that i can connect to application.

Comment: even if you are doing through sc use --console to see what is happening and error messages

Comment: Please provide command for that . Is it `sc create binPath= "c:/Mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --console --defaults-file=c:\mysql\my_xx.ini` or `sc create --console binPath= "c:/Mysql/bin/mysqld.exe  --defaults-file=c:\mysql\my_xx.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=> only set my_ibt.ini  in the pateh C:\RailsInstaller\
=> my_xxx.ini

```
[mysqld_xxx]
#if already installed then use that basedir
basedir = "C:\RailsInstaller\MYSQL"

#where you want to set your database
datadir="C:\RailsInstaller\MYSQL\data"
port = 43307
enable-named-pipe
socket = mypipe1
```

In the command promt which runs as administrator go to
\MYSQL\bin>
And run Command :

`mysqld --install mysqld_xxx --defaults-file=C:\RailsInstaller\my_xxx.ini`

Service successfully installed.

Then :

`net start mysqld_xxx`

The mysqld_ibt service is starting.
The mysqld_ibt service was started successfully.

Comment: I have solved the issue by own which works for both windows xp and windows 7 equally